# Destroy pointers to objects in array

Tags: c++, arrays

Say I want to declare an array of pointers to a specific object like

```
Object *objects = new Object[size];
```

and then add some new objects to my dynamically allocated array

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

    Object* obj = new obj;
    objects[i] = *obj;

}
```

is it enough to deallocate all memory by just calling `delete[]` on the array, or do I have to loop through the array first and call `delete` on each object? Or is this stupid to do in practice?

Comment: You're not declaring an array of pointers. Do you really want to declare one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to follow the deallocation is reverse order of allocation.

So number of times `new` that many times `delete` , similarly number of times `new []` that many times `delete []`

---

```
// Assuming objects as array of pointers [ Object **objects ]
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
   delete objects[i] ;
}

delete [] objects;
```

And your *correct* allocation should go as:

```
Object **objects= new Object*[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
    objects[i] = new Object;
}
```

Also , you should use smart pointers `std::unique_ptr` for hassle free memory management

`std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Object> > objects ;`

Answer (score 5):

You always have to `delete` everything you `new` in some way. That means, you would need to `delete obj` in every iteration to avoid leaks. Note that you never really store the `Object` `obj` points to, but a copy of it.

The way you do it right know is quite unusual and not very handy anyway: The loop you showed does nothing useful since the `new Objects[size]` already default constructed your `Objects`. In particular, it does not add any elements, they are already there. You could just leave that out. If you want to change the content of your array, e.g. do more initialization, your loop would usually look more like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    objects[i] = newValue;    
}
```

Remember, the `Objects` are already there after `new Objects[size]`!

In practice, you would be *much* better of with a

```
std::vector<Object> objects(size);
```

(or maybe, if the above does not fit your usecase, a

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects(size);
```

, but I feel like that is unlikely to be the case). For a good overview of what a `std::vector` can do and how to use it, read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Probably most importantly for you: You can index it just like an array.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are storing an array of Objects and not pointers to Object. This means that they won't be deleted when you delete the array and the memory will leak.
2. If you want to store pointers to Objects in your array then you need to declare it as `Object **objects = new Object *[size];` and then you will have to delete all the pointers in the array.

So the better code will look like:

```
//Allocation:
Object **objects = new Object *[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    objects[i] = new Object;
}

//Deletion
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    delete objects[i];
}
delete [] objects;
```

An even better solution would be to use vectors and smart pointers and then you don't need the deletion code at all.

```
//Allocation:
vector<unique_ptr<Object>> objects;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    objects.push_back(make_unique(new Object));
}

//Deletion
//Hey where did all the code go.
```